# Altering specific field value in an object array Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Ive a class like this

```
class security
{
 public id:number;
 public name:string;
}
```

Then I have an array of security as follows

```
let s:security[]=[{id:1,name:'Alex'},{id:2,name:'John'},{id:3,name:'Philip'},{id:4,name:'Mark'},{id:5,name:'Thomas'}];
```

So a function if I pass the value 0, it will change all names of the array as empty string. If I pass an ID, name should change for that specific ID only.

What I tried was

```
var id=1;
let s2:security[]=s.find(x=>x.id==id);
```

Then I have to loop through s2 and change the values. But I guess for both the case rather than looping we can do that change all something like **select** method in **linq**

So how can we change object array values for all object or selected without using loop

Answer (score 1):

The `find` does not return an array, so `s2` is an object. You could just do:

```
s2.name = '';
```

However, if you need to change all values (in vanilla js) you have to interate the array.

```
s.forEach(item => item.name = '');
```

Comment: OK.. I am using Foreach. But using callback function there.. Not this way as you suggested. Will try this.. Thanks

Comment: Arrow functions came with ES6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do operations on several elements of an array (array of objects in your case) without having a loop. As a suggestion, you can use javascript's for...of loop if you do not use any library.

```
for (var security of s) {
  console.log(security);
  // do your operation here
}
```